# Cordova 6.2.3 has no WebChromeClient,how can i override the onJsPrompt()?

Tags: java, android, cordova, webchromeclient

when I update my project from cordova 3 to cordova 6,I find there is no WebChromeClient,but my project used this Class and override the onJsPrompt().
Now,how should i do base on Cordova 6  to override OnJsPrompt()

`package com.qtby.gxwlc;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import com.jsdemo.ClientTool;
import com.jsdemo.JsNativeFunc;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.webkit.JsPromptResult;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class CustomerWebChromeClient extends CordovaChromeClient {
    public CustomerWebChromeClient(CordovaInterface ctx, CordovaWebView app){
        super(ctx, app);
    }

    JsNativeFunc jsNativeFunc;

    public JsNativeFunc getJsNativeFunc(){
        return jsNativeFunc;
    }

    public boolean isJsNativeFunc(int requestCode){
        if(jsNativeFunc == null)
            return false;
        return jsNativeFunc.isJsNativeFunc(requestCode);
    }

    public void jsResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent){
        jsNativeFunc.jsResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String origin, String message,
            String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
        if(ClientTool.callNativeFunc(message)){
                return super.onJsPrompt(view, origin, message, defaultValue, result);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onJsPrompt(view, origin, message, defaultValue, result);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You do this now.

```
import org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient;
```

`extends SystemWebChromeClient`

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java

Cheers